# Superfluid Vortex Lines Bifurcation and Winding Numbers

Tags: condensed-matter, topology, vortex, superfluidity, bifurcation

Vortex lines in superfluids are characterized by their quantised circulation: $k = \frac{h}{m}\times n$, where $n$ is the winding number in the sense of a topological winding number. Now, most vortex lines want to be $n=1$ as this is the lowest energy state, but this raises a question that my supervisor couldn't answer: can vortex lines bifurcate? We want this answer to be yes, but I have read that there is no way to continuously deform a winding number of $n$ into $m$ where $n$ is not equal to $m$. However, is this also true for the case where, say, $n=2$ and $m=2\times 1$? i.e. we have this bifurcation I mentioned.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by bifurcate in this context?

Comment: If you are talking about a vortex with $n>1$ splitting up into many $n=1$ vortices, yes that is allowed and usually more stable

Comment: Yes that's exactly it thankyou.